# active_scaffold routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If you haven't seen my question yesterday, this is my second rails app.  The first went nice and smooth, but this one keeps giving me one random error after another.  I installed active_scaffold for this app as well as the last app (the first error, instead of using script/install plugin git://active_scaffold repository, I did script/install plugin **http**://active_scaffold repository.)  I didn't want to spell out basic CRUD on minor models.  After the install problems, (before I found the http solution from a *windows* user when I'm on Linux) I thought I'd try out Hobo.  Well, Hobo updated actionmailer, actionpack, activerecord, activeresource, and installed rack.  Rails isn't even using the updated versions.  But as you can see at the bottom of the trace it's using rack.  I have a feeling it has something to do with my futzing around with installing Hobo which I uninstalled.  Thanks in advance.

[Edit]
I had asked the question over at the 
[ActiveScaffold Group](http://groups.google.com/group/activescaffold/browse_frm/thread/c10f054054115569#)
the answer (if you don't want to follow the link) was that this line needed to be added to routes:

```
map.resources :modelName, :active_scaffold => true
```

It doesn't entirely answer my question, since the documentation said nothing about changing routes.  But, it works.

[/Edit]

### ActionController::RoutingError in Departments#index

Showing vendor/plugins/active_scaffold/frontends/default/views/_list_header.html.erb where line #8 raised:

```
No route matches {:_method=>:get, :action=>"show_search", :controller=>"departments"}
```

Extracted source (around line #8):

```
5:       <% next if controller.respond_to? link.security_method and !controller.send(link.security_method) -%>
6:    <% next if link.action == 'new' && params[:nested].nil? && active_scaffold_config.list.always_show_create %>
7:    <% next if link.action == 'show_search' && active_scaffold_config.list.always_show_search %>
8:       <%= render_action_link(link, new_params) -%>
9:     <% end -%>
10: 
11:     <%= loading_indicator_tag(:action => :table) %>
```

Trace of template inclusion: vendor/plugins/active_scaffold/frontends/default/views/list.html.erb

[Full Trace](http://funfun.v.cryptomeme.com/stacktrace.txt)  It was taking forever to format it.  I'm still not fully conversant in SO's formatting (sometimes the server is down.  reboots are reinstalls.  it's a play server)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to routes:

```
map.resources :modelName, :active_scaffold => true
```

And, contrary to my edit, it **is** in the documentation.  It's in the wiki at [Github](http://wiki.github.com/activescaffold/active_scaffold/getting-started).  My second question at SO, and I could have found the answer by RTFM'ing.  <sigh>

Answer (score 2):

For Rails 4+ at least, your entry in config/routes.rb should look like:

```
resources :models do # my model name in plural
  as_routes
  # for action links of type member, add the following
  # see also [note, via the action-link API, you can change the HTTP verb.  Adjust this route accordingly.
  # https://github.com/activescaffold/active_scaffold/wiki/Adding-custom-actions
  # get :my_custom_action, :on => :member
end
```

Note, getting the right version of the Gem requires the following config in your Gemfile:

```
 gem 'active_scaffold', github: 'activescaffold/active_scaffold', :branch => "3-4-stable"
```

If you get an error that "as_routes" isn't found; that'd be the problem.

**THIS IS RAILS 4 ONLY**

Comment: 3 years on I found myself upgrading another Rails app to Rails 4.2, and can confirm that this recipe was the magic ticket [again].

Answer (score 0):

For Rails 5.x you can set route as follow:

```
resources :model, concerns: :active_scaffold
```